# Creating a custom class attributer in QuillJS

Tags: quill

I'm trying to create a custom class attributer in QuillJS.
I've got this far:

```
let config = {
  scope: Parchment.Scope.BLOCK,
};

let MClass = new Parchment.Attributor.Class('mark', 'dom-mark', config);
Quill.register(MClass,true)
```

But when attempting:

```
this.quillEditor.format('mark', 'MarkThisHere');
```

I get:

ERROR TypeError: BlotClass.create is not a function

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Works for me in this [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmdmJy).

```
Parchment = Quill.import('parchment');

let config = {
  scope: Parchment.Scope.BLOCK,
};

let MClass = new Parchment.Attributor.Class('mark', 'dom-mark', config);
Quill.register(MClass,true)

var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      [{ header: [1, 2, false] }],
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
      ['image', 'code-block']
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
});

quill.format('mark', 'MarkThisHere');
```

Comment: Hi Ben Browitt, thanks for the example. Can you further help me and explain what the last line does? Is this executed once and quill knows then to format all blocks with this class or how does it work? And how can I apply this to `li` elements? Because that's what I need in the end, adding a custom class to `li` tags. Thanks!

Comment: Format text at user’s current selection. You can read about it in the docs https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#format

Comment: For anybody using Quill 2 the line `let MClass = new Parchment.Attributor.Class('mark', 'dom-mark', config);` needs to be changed to `let MClass = new Parchment.ClassAttributor('mark', 'dom-mark', config);`