# Quilljs: TypeError when deriving custom Attributor

Tags: typescript, quill

I'm trying to implement a potentially overlapping attribute as in this question: [Overlapping Inline Annotations with Quill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45359148/overlapping-inline-annotations-with-quill) and this issue: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1216

Only difference is that I'm using TypeScript. This is an excerpt of my code:

```
import Quill from "quill";
import Parchment from "parchment";

class Comment extends Parchment.Attributor.Attribute {
    constructor(attrName = 'comment', keyName = 'data-comment') {
        super(attrName, keyName, { scope: Parchment.Scope.INLINE_ATTRIBUTE })
    }

    add(node: HTMLElement, value: any) : boolean {
        if (this.canAdd(node, value)) {
            let ids: string[] = []

            if (node.hasAttribute(this.keyName)) {
                ids = node.getAttribute(this.keyName)!.split(',')
            }

            if (ids.indexOf(value) < 0) {
                ids.push(value)
            }

            node.setAttribute(this.keyName, ids.sort().join(','))

            return true
        }
        else
        {
            return false
        }
    }

    remove(node: HTMLElement) {
        node.removeAttribute(this.keyName)
    }

    value(node: HTMLElement) : string {
        return node.getAttribute(this.keyName) || "";
    }
}

Quill.register({
    'formats/comment': new Comment()
});

let customCommentHandler = () => {
    // get the position of the cursor
    let range = this.editor.getSelection();
    if (range) {
        this.editor.formatText(range.index, range.length, "comment", this.counter);
        this.counter += 1;
    }
};
```

This compiles fine but when I actually try to apply this via the custom handler I get a `TypeError: BlotClass.create is not a function` at 
`quill.js:181`

Any idea as to what I am doing wrong?

edit: forgot to mention that this question kind of answers the same problem: [Creating a custom class attributer in QuillJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219124/creating-a-custom-class-attributer-in-quilljs?rq=1) However, that poster used JavaScript and only instantiated the Attributor instead of deriving it. They solved the problem by importing Parchment differently. I tried that and that makes TypeScript complain that `super` is not known in my constructor, since `Parchment` is of type `Any`. By importing parchment with `let Parchment = Quill.import("parchment");` I lose all the type info and my derived Attributor doesn't compile any more.

---

I found a workaround for now. Apparently `import Parchment from "parchment";` doesn't work currently, as has been described in this question: ["BlotClass.create is not a function" when trying to create a custom attributor in Quill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373448)

When I use `let Parchment = Quill.import("parchment");` the compiler complains when I call `super`. So I "faked" the typeinfo by deriving like this:

```
let Parchment = Quill.import('parchment');
class Comment extends (Parchment.Attributor.Class as { new(attrName: any, keyName: any, options: any): any; } ){
    constructor(attrName = 'comment', keyName = 'comment') {
        super(attrName, keyName, { scope: Parchment.Scope.INLINE_ATTRIBUTE });
    }

    // rest of the class goes here
}
```

By supplying the contstructor artificially I can at least call it. It compiles without complaining and works.

Needless to say that this is not a very satisfying solution as I lose  benefits of TypeScript, like code completion and proper type checking and I have to add annoying boilerplate code as a workaround.

I still hope there can be a better solution for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373448/blotclass-create-is-not-a-function-when-trying-to-create-a-custom-attributor-i seems like a similar issue but was not in Typescript so I was able to try it out. The answer there whenever the OP responds might be the same answer for this issue