# "BlotClass.create is not a function" when trying to create a custom attributor in Quill

Tags: javascript, quill

I'm trying to create a custom style attributor in Quill to use inline styles for indentation. All I have so far is the bare minimum:

```
class Indent extends Parchment.Attributor.Style {}

const IndentStyle = new Indent('indent', 'margin-left', {
  scope: Parchment.Scope.BLOCK
});
Quill.register(IndentStyle, true);
```

However, when I try to apply the indent formatting via a toolbar button, I get this error in the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: BlotClass.create is not a function
    at Object.create (quill.js:184)
    at Block.ShadowBlot.replaceWith (quill.js:5200)
    at Block.FormatBlot.replaceWith (quill.js:3610)
    at Block.FormatBlot.format (quill.js:3597)
    at BlockBlot.format (quill.js:7250)
    at eval (quill.js:2513)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval (quill.js:2510)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Editor.formatLine (quill.js:2506)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not getting any issues with your code: https://codepen.io/quill/pen/jYJOdp. How are you applying the formatting?

Comment: I'm applying the formatting by just having a toolbar button with the class `ql-indent` with a value of `+1` or `-1`. The only difference I can see from my code and yours is that I am pulling in Parchment like this:

`import Parchment from 'parchment';`

(This is TypeScript code, BTW.)

Comment: Update: I tried the code in your example, and I'm getting a TypeScript error. On the line where I am instantiating a `new Indent`, TypeScript complains `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target`. Is there some other step I need with TypeScript to make this work?

Comment: If you change your code to use Quill.import does the error go away?

Comment: Using Quill.import is what seems to cause the TypeScript error. It's like it doesn't recognize the arguments of the parent class or something.

Comment: The codepen example I posted uses the code you posted and Quill.imports and it's working just fine in Javascript. Seems like the Typescript build pipeline warrants investigation.

Comment: I had a similar problem here and found a (very unsatisfying) workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270372 Maybe it can help you. I still hope for a proper fix though.