# Quill: How to apply a CSS style to the some text programmatically?

Tags: html, css, quill

As part of a search function in my application, I need to apply a CSS style to a portion of the text present in the editor.

I found [this page](https://www.scalablepath.com/blog/using-quill-js-build-wysiwyg-editor-website/) which seems to show how to do this by using `Attributor`. However, it demonstrates applying the style by pressing a button which is recognized by Quill and not the actual code to do it programmatically.
`formatText` seems to be a possibility but it requires defining the style in the function call while the style is in a loaded css file.

In a "regular" context, I would wrap the text in a span and set a class attribute on it.

What is the Quill way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

[This stackoverflow issue may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219124/creating-a-custom-class-attributer-in-quilljs): it allows you to define a new Parchment format to handle custom class through Quill attributes.

[This Quill issue too](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/pull/1217): How to create your custom marker and a way/method to **clean** all markers

My guess to achieve what you are trying to do is to find the text inside your Quill document and then apply the `formatText` with your custom attribute to add the right class producing the right color. Clean then properly once search finished